# Homotopy invariant algebras over topological operads

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories, operads

In the Markl-Schnider-Stasheff' [MSS] book on operads, the authors say that the W-construction of a topological operad P is cofibrant, and they do not ask explicitly another conditions on P. By the Berger-Moerdijk' results I think at least P must be well-pointed and \Sigma-cofibrant in the Quillen model structure on top (compac. gener. spaces), in order to ensure WP is cofibrant. Can someone confirm it to me, please?

[MSS] also say that WP algebras structures can be transferred under homotopy equivalences. Does it hold with respect any cofibrant operad Q?